# Datetime picker in inline kendo grid in which cannot select past date

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using kendo date time picker in kendo in line grid.

In that on click of edit I cannot get date time picker only date picker. in that I want to disable past date are disable. so he can select only current or future date only.

```js
var firstNames = ["Nancy", "Andrew", "Janet", "Margaret", "Steven", "Michael", "Robert", "Laura", "Anne", "Nige"];
var lastNames = [ "Davolio", "Fuller", "Leverling", "Peacock", "Buchanan", "Suyama", "King", "Callahan", "Dodsworth", "White" ];

function createRandomData(count) {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var firstName = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
        var lastName = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
        var date = "2013-10-10T05:02:40.44";
        data.push({
            Id: i + 1,
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            Date: date
        });
    }
    return data;
}

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data    : createRandomData(10),
        pageSize: 10,
        schema  : {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Id       : { type: 'number' },
                    FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                    LastName : { type: 'string' },
                    Date: { type: 'date' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    editable  : "inline",
    pageable  : {
        refresh  : true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    columns   : [
        { command : "edit", width: 90 },
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 90, title: "Last Name" },
        {
            field       : "Date",
            title       : "Date",
            format      : "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
            parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zz"]
        }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: this is fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/Ahq6s/461/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a date editor and then set min to datepicker to today.

```
        {
            field       : "Date",
            title       : "Date",
            format      : "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
            parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zz"], 
            editor: dateEditor 
        }
```

Please see related fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ahq6s/462/

Comment: but i want datetime picker when its edit as you can see in you fiddler link http://jsfiddle.net/Ahq6s/462/

Comment: and i want also setting that he can select upto 1 year date from current date. i have tried but its not working. my link is : http://jsfiddle.net/Ahq6s/463/

Comment: No its not working in your fiddler i have checked i can't see datetime picker in kendo editable mode grid.

Comment: your solution is great but its effected time also so is any way that is not effected with time in date&time picker in kendo inline grid.your fiddler link is:- jsfiddle.net/Ahq6s/466

Comment: Not sure i understand. You want to be able on the last day to select any time?

Comment: i want to say in fiddler time field you see the time is 2:53 PM etc. you are not able to see 2:00 AM time in time selector. and also why its show current time not like 2:00 AM & 2:00 PM